Latitude inversion when opening nc file with nc_open
I'm facing an issue when opening a nc file in R using the nc_open function. The images contained in this nc file are inverted in the latitude axe. This could append because I'm working in the South hemisphere ? My projection: EPSG:32735
Here is the representation of what is noticed:
When opening the file in QGis:

When opening the file in R:

Here is the code I use to open it:
nc_turb <- nc_open("C:/Users/aurel/OneDrive/Documents/Memoire/Datasets/TSMi/TSMi_AR_mosaic/TSMi_AR.nc")
names(nc_turb$var)
NDTI_turb <- ncvar_get(nc_turb, varid="__xarray_dataarray_variable__")
image(c(1:1104), c(1:2093), NDTI_turb[,,2])


If you can share the file we can help a lot more specifically, otherwise some general comments and approaches (aka guesswork) in answer below.

You're using the ncdf package functions which are only reading the raw matrix data, so it gets assigned coordinates from 1:n and 1:m for an nxm grid. The projection and true coordinate info is ignored. They should be stored in other vars and dims of the NetCDF, and if the file isn't a standard geospatial format (and NetCDF is a general data store for any vector or N-dimensional data) you'll have to extract the coordinates and create a raster object using the terra package with the coordinates from the NetCDF variables and dimensions.
If the NetCDF does conform to geospatial standards, then terra::rast should be able to read it in correctly, and you dont need the NetCDF-related functions. You may have to specify sub-datasets or otherwise tweak the file name. Check QGIS' info about the layer to see how GDAL (the underlying geospatial raster library, used by QGIS and terra) is dealing with it.
